# Prolog list of list n number with condition

Tags: prolog

I'm studying prolog language and i have an issue regarding this problem.

I've already created a program that, given a number `N`, returns a list with elements between `0` and `N`:

```
list2val(N,L):- list2val(0,N,L).

list2val(N,N,[N]).
list2val(C,N,[C|T]):- 
    C<N,
    N1 is C+1,
    list2val(N1,N,T).

?- list2val(5,X).
X = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now i'm trying to give an extension that, given a list, returns a list of lists in which every list is `list2val` only if the next number is greater than current number. In this case:

```
?- newFuction([1,5,2,3,9],L). 
L = [[0,1],[0,1,2,],[0,1,2,3]]
```

My code is this, but somethings is wrong:

```
array(X):- array(X,_L).
array([],_L).

array([H|[T|Ts]],L1):- 
    H<T, 
    list2val(H,L2),
    array([T|Ts],[L1|[L2]]).
array([T|Ts],L1).
```

Maybe could be too much difficult to understand but using a list `L = [1,5,2,3,9]` i do those steps:

- check 1<5 so i create a 1 list2val until 1..in this case [0,1]
- check 5<2 i dont create nothing.
- check 2<3 i create list2val of 2 ...[0,1,2]
- and so on...

I don't want use a standard predicates, by implement with standard terms.

Comment: So you want to find a list (`List`) consisting of all numbers `X` between `0` and `N`? 
`findall(X, between(0, N, X), List).`

Comment: Nope.I want you to give a list, I find all the sublists (which are made up of numbers from 0 to N according to the function I have already done), and these lists are formed only if the current number is smaller than the next. @firefrorefiddle .. By the way i edit the question with another example

Comment: What happens when you call `array([9], X)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for your problem could be:

```
list2val(N,L):- list2val(0,N,L).

list2val(N,N,[N]):- !.
list2val(C,N,[C|T]):- 
    C<N,
    N1 is C+1,
list2val(N1,N,T).

simulate([_],[]).
simulate([A,B|T],[H|T1]):-
    ( A < B ->
        list2val(A,H),
        simulate([B|T],T1);
        simulate([B|T],[H|T1])
    ).
```

Using a predicate like `simulate/2`, you can solve your problem: it compares two numbers of the list and then create a new list in case the condition is satisfied.

```
?- simulate([1,5,2,3,9],LO).
LO = [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
false
```

Comment: Thanks Damiano for answear, but i wish implement by my self, with no standard predicates. I will add in a question.

Comment: There is no standard prdicate... simulate/2 is a predicate i wrote, is not a part of a library

Comment: Really thanks Damiano.. In the first simulate ([_],[]) you assume that if i have one element in list is sure a empty list? (atom)....right? So this predicate close the recursion when remains one elements inside the list

Comment: If there is only one element in the list, i cannot call `list2val/2`. In your example, the recursion stops when `simulate([9],L)` is called. If there is only one element in the list, the recursion stops

Comment: Another issue that i have in my code, that every time that compute list2val the return override the previuos result of list2val. In particular i call on the 1, return [0,1] i call on the 2 i return [0,1,2] but dont append in list [[0,1],[0,1,2,]].. Can you know why that?